# Advice For A New Senior DBA

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

I'm finally taking the plunge and moving up from Junior DBA at a large organisation to Senior DBA at a smaller place running SQL Server. It's going to take some time for me to get a good picture of the businesses' requirements and things might be in a bit of a state as they've been without a DBA for 6 months or so.

Is there any advice you would give to a someone starting in this position barring the things like producing a list of SQL Server instances, finding out restore point and recovery time targets, and trying to decipher what state things were left in?

Thanks!

Comment: You could, you know, ask - "Hello, I'm new here. What do you think the priorities are and what do you want me to work on first?" Then listen to the old hands who've been there for a while. They know which closets have skeletons in them.

Comment: Well yeah :) Not planning on going in all guns blazing and laying down my own brand of ill informed rules! Starting any new endeavor is a a ton of listening first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you've already suggested, as soon as I got there I'd perform an inventory of all SQL Servers before then spending time running the latest version of [sp_Blitz® – Free SQL Server Health Check Script](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) and auditing the results.

Depending on the results I'd then probably look to get in and standardise Ola Hallengrens [SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html). You can then concentrate on running checkDB, index maintenance and getting backups offsite, security (logins, linked servers) etc.

Once the data is safe, I'd then look to either bring in a third party monitoring solution or build a basic one myself. At a minimum, I'd start capturing wait stats every minute or so.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've got hold of Brent & Co.'s latest scripts to take with me and I've been getting familiar with Ola's awesome backup scripts as well which I'm finding a big (positive) departure from Maintenance Plans.

Comment: ...and then start revoking sysadmin from all the unnecessary logins(!)

Comment: They're going to be everywhere aren't they :/